# Работа с архивами Zip в Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Порекомендуйте бесплатный  компонент Delphi 7 для работы с архивами Zip. В инете накопал ZipMaster, fwZip. Какие Вы используете?

Answer (score 1):

Используем [Abbrevia](http://tpabbrevia.sourceforge.net/). Бесплатно, есть исходники, лицензия MPL.

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный не устраивает? (zlib до зипа доработать можно.)

Comment: так "доработать" или "сандартный" ? :-D

Кстати, был ли zlib в Delphi 7 ?

Comment: Стандартный ZLib, но он не создает заголовка зип файла, только сжимает по алгоритму Идиентичному zip,  названия не помню уже))

Comment: Либо deflate/inflate либо еще боле тарый implode/explode
Но для простого и быстрого на том же Delphi Inspirations есть UCL (библиотека upx.sf.net), а для обмена с внешним миром таки надо и заголовок

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/181974/delhi-gzip-zlib
как то так, стандартная библиотека Zlib, становится zip\gz архивом)

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал ZipForge еще в [JEDI VCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/) есть целыый набор компонентов для работы с разного рода архивами на вкладке JV Encrypt, Compress

Comment: Только не JediVCL а в Jedi CodeLib - там интерфейс к библиотекам 7-zip.rg

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь **[библиотекой 7z](http://www.7-zip.org/)** и **[оберткой к ней](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=13)**