# Delhi gzip zlib

Tags: delphi, zip

Есть **строка** пожата Zlib  на делфях..
Есть скрипт пхп который принимает эту строку.

Задача получить разжатую строку в php.

**Ищу готовое решение\компонент** для делфей(gzip) или php(аля func unzipstr(s:source):string...)

Стандартный gzip не желает кушать zipованые делфей строки(только ли строки?).

Повторюсь обмен ведется **строками**! **не файлами**!

Все что встречал для php разжимает именно файлы(или я что то не так ищу или делаю)...

Comment: Решение нашел под д2010 и переделал, как прилепить файл? может пригодится кому, возможности, архивация\разархивирование потока\строки полностью совместимо с gzip, это просто обертка над zlib.

Comment: Залейте на pastebin.com и выложите ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готовый модуль для архивации GZip(используя zlib) тестировался на Delphi XE2
Основные функции:

```
{===================================Строки=======================================}
//Архивация
function  GZCompressStr(const s: String; const fileName, comment: String;dateTime: TDateTime): String; overload;

function  GZCompressStr(const s: String): String; overload;

//Разархивирование 
function  GZDecompressStr(const s: String; var fileName, comment: String; var dateTime: TDateTime): String; overload;

function  GZDecompressStr(const s: String): String; overload;

{===================================Потоки=======================================}
//Архивация
procedure GZCompressStream(inStream, outStream: TStream; const fileName,comment: String; dateTime: TDateTime); overload;

procedure GZCompressStream(inStream, outStream: TStream); overload;

//Разархивирование
procedure GZDecompressStream(inStream, outStream: TStream; var fileName,comment: String; var dateTime: TDateTime); overload;

procedure GZDecompressStream(inStream, outStream: TStream); overload;
```

[ZLibExGZ.pas](http://pastebin.com/JfHZCMyK)

Пы.сы. модуль является адаптацией под Rad2, найден на просторах интернетов.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала покажите как вы делаете. Используйте тот же zlib и на php.

Comment: Uses zlib;

Procedure compress;
Var
  t:TCompressionStream;
  fs:TFileStream;
Begin
  fs:=TFileStream.Create('c:/123.zip',fmOpenReadWrite or fmCreate);
  t:=TZCompressionStream.Create(fs);
  t.write(данные,размер);
  t.free;
  fs.free;
end; Это архивация на стороне Delphi. Собсно на этом и заканчивается то что работает)
если со стороны пхп то, там сжимает сам сервер(как он жмет меня мало интересовало, но проверки показали что размер данных уменьшиля с 2мб до 200кб). На делфе использую сторонний компонент для **разархивирования**, который не умеет архивировать.

Comment: zlib на пхп это совсем не та библиотека что на делфе(или обёртки у них разные) в интернете куча тем как с помощью zlib(Delphi) **разархивировать** gzip генерируемый zlib(php), но ни слова об обратном, создании gzip c помощью zlib(Delphi).

Comment: Прощу прощенья, отладочный код поклал, там мэмори стрим и запись из него в строку с последующей отправкой

Answer (score 0):

> Стандартный gzip не желает кушать zipованые делфей строки(только ли строки?).

Что и логично. `zlib` и `gzip` это разные вещи.

Для работы с `gzip`-ом в Delphi воспользуйтесь [Abbrevia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/).

Comment: **Отличия** между gzip и zip только **в заголовках** и контрольных суммах.
алгоритм сжатия 1 и тот же в обоих случаях. (верно для zlib 1.2.x и zip 2.x)

**Вариант решения 1)** нужно дописать до полученого zlib`ом результата заголовки и контрольные суммы чтобы иметь на выходе верный gz.
 
**Вариант решения 2)** перенос(выковыривание из нед zlib`а пхпшного) функции zlib_decode поддержка которой начинается с php5.4(у меня 5.2 обновить не выйдет)

http://www.php.net/zlib

Comment: пы.сы Abbrevia не умеет работать с gzip или я этого там незаметил.

Comment: > пы.сы Abbrevia не умеет работать с gzip или я этого там незаметил.
>

Умеет:

>
>Abbrevia is a compression toolkit for Delphi, C++Builder, Kylix, and Free Pascal. 
> 
> It supports compressing and decompressing PKZIP, Microsoft CAB, tar, **gzip**, and bzip2 archives, and can create self-extracting executables. On Windows it also provides Delphi wrappers for the LZMA, Bzip2, and WavPack SDKs, and PPMd decompression.

Comment: Что там написано я читал(задолго до того как задал тут вопрос), вы мне ткните пальцом в строчку как это использовать) тар,каб,зип - нашел, gzip нет! нашел пару статей, где описано что ее можно заставить **разархивировать** gzip и то нужно править ее код, а как заставить ее создать валидный gzip - нигде не сказано(в примерах к ней тоже нет).

Comment: Плюс основное что я искал так это функцию\компонент с возможностью вытворять такое со строками, Abbrevia делает это с файлами(и вроде можно доизвращатся до потоков, чтоб не плодить файлы).