# Архивация строки Delphi

Tags: delphi, 7z, архивация

Добрый день товарищи!

Возникла следующая задача: Необходимо архивировать некую достаточно большую строку перед записью в БД.

Сделал это через временный файл + 7z.exe, но как-то громоздко получилось. Не совсем кошерно что-ли. Можно ли реализовать подобное без создания временных файлов и т.д. - на лету?

ЗЫ Delphi 7

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/181974/delphi-delhi-gzip-zlib

Comment: Видел это - но ZLib в Delphi 7 нет встроенного

Comment: Тогда как всегда^

 - [Abbrevia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/)
 - [ZipForge](http://www.componentace.com/zip_component_zip_delphi_zipforge.htm)

Comment: У ZipForge не нашёл возможности из TStringStream архивировать в другой TStringStream минуя создание файла. Есть  AddFromStream и ExtractFromStream которые в результате записывают / читают конкретный файл на диске. Те же яйца только в профиль

Comment: Зы. он там точно есть, только старая версия, кстати при небольшой модификации мой исходник реально скормить 7ой делфе без всякого гемороя получить кодирование строк на лету(без файлов). единственная добавочка от себя, вы не сможете без делфей разархивировать строку, или таки адаптируйте файл(по ссылке) под свою версию)

Comment: Благодарю. Действительно проблема была в старом Zlib-е. обновил и жить стало веселей. Отмечу ваш ответ как принятый. хотя больше мне помог именно коммент про старый Zlib )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите мои вопросы, там же ответ от меня, и в делфи 7 есть Zlib, могу кинуть пример если сами не разберетесь.

[Delhi gzip zlib](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/181974/delphi-delhi-gzip-zlib)

Answer (score 0):

А смысл архивировать строку держа ее в БД?
Теряете многие преимущества.
если нужно уменьшить занимаемый обьем архивируйте базу.
как вариант сохраняйте в файл, файл архивируйте , а в базе держите только ссылку на файл с атрибутами.
Возможно имеет смысл разбивать строку на части, и использовать справочник, тут нужно понять что за строка и зачем её архивировать.

Comment: Смысл исключительно для ускорения удаленной работы пользователей. Далеко не везде в пределах нашей необъятной родины адекватный интернет и пересылка строки в 50-60 Мб не всегда радует пользователей своей скоростью. 

**Теряете многие преимущества** - нет. Поиска по этой строке не производится и не будет в дальнейшем (это строка настроек некого шаблона, которая из-за своей структуры замечательно архивируется в сотню-две Кб) Профит от архивирования строки в вышеописанных условиях - огромнейший.

Comment: Сразу по поводу способа хранения - Да, ввиду особенностей задачи это надо хранить исключительно в БД, так что с этой точки зрения всё что можно уже оптимизировано. Осталось решить проблему архивирования при помощи Stream-ов

Comment: Если задача в удаленном транспорте, то не архивируйте строк в базу, а при зпросе из базы лейте в файл и отправляйте архив клиенту.